# is there a recommended limit to using parallel CURL operations

Tags: php, curl, concurrency, parallel-processing, download

suppose I use CURL MULTI to perform parallel operations (upload/download etc)

Is there a recommended maximum limit of parallel operations that I can perform or can I set it so that it runs, for instance, 100 operations in parallel? What about 1000?

What sort of factors should I consider when I specify the number of concurrent operations using CURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1000 CURL in parallel you will need a good bandwidth, the recommended amount of parallel requests can be found by debugging, set a function to check for timed-out connections and in that case decrease / increase the limit, or timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

This answer to this question is dependent on your network capacity, the capacity of your NIC, and what you are trying to optimize.

- If you are trying to minimize latency of a single request, the answer is quite possible 1 or something close to 1.
- If you are trying to maximize throughput, then you should keep increasing the number of parallel operations until your throughput peaks and then either plateaus or falls. That will be the sweet spot.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will open at most 4 connections at a time to a single server. That's probably a good guideline.

If you're downloading from different servers, the only problem may be that you'll use up lots of local TCP ports, and this might interfere with other applications on the system. It won't get in the way of connections TO the server, since those all use the same local port 80 (or 443 for SSL). But if you have other applications using CURL, or your machine sends mail, they might not be able to get an outgoing port if you use them all up. There are typically 15-30K ephemeral ports, so you could probably get away with using 1,000 of them.